# Error HH12 while trying to run npx hardhat command via ssh using nohup

Tags: node.js, ssh, nohup, hardhat

I'm having issues running npx hardhart command on my remote server via ssh and keeping the node task running while the ssh terminal is closed.

I can remotely connect to my VPS server (Ubuntu 22.04) via ssh and run the following command from the ssh terminal in my hardhat project root directory

```
npx hardhat run scripts/index.js --network goerli
```

This ran successfully and the node server was started, But when I try to use `nohup` to keep the node.js server running while the terminal is closed; in this way

```
ssh root@10.10.10.10 "nohup npx hardhat run /var/www/myprojectroot/scripts/index.js --network goerli  > /var/www/outputs/hardhat.out 2>&1 &"
```

the ssh session closes and I get the following error in `/var/www/outputs/hardhat.out`

```
Error HH12: Trying to use a non-local installation of Hardhat, which is not supported.
Please install Hardhat locally using npm or Yarn, and try again.

HardhatError: HH12: Trying to use a non-local installation of Hardhat, which is not supported.
Please install Hardhat locally using npm or Yarn, and try again.
    at main (/root/.npm/_npx/ef9ef3f50c7d7dc1/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/cli/cli.ts:180:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/.npm/_npx/ef9ef3f50c7d7dc1/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/cli/cli.ts:377:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/.npm/_npx/ef9ef3f50c7d7dc1/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/cli/bootstrap.ts:16:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
```

The full path of the script is specified in the command, so I don't know why I am having this error.

NB: 10.10.10.10 is just for reference purposes, It's not an actual server IP.